# Is the function $\eta$ surjective?

Tags: commutative-algebra, equivalence-relations, localization

Let $D$ be a domain. Let $D^{*}$ be the set of non-zero elements of $D$. We define a relation $\sim$ on $D\times D^{*}$ as follows: $(a, b)\sim(c, d)$ if and only if $ad=bs$. It is easily checked that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. We denote the equivalence classes with respect to this relation as $a/b$. Let $F$ denote the quotient set.

The map $\eta$ from $D$ into $F$ such that every element $a$ in $D$ goes to $a/1$ is a monomorphism.

I wonder to know whether this function is surjective?
So for every fraction $a/b$ in $F$ can we find an  element $a$ in $D$ such that $\eta({a})=a/b$?

Would you help me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Set $D=\mathbb Z$. Then $1/2=a/1$ leads to  contradiction.

Comment: The idea behind this definition: the set $F$ is the field of fractions of the ring $D$, i.e. the natural extension of $D$ in which every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse. If $D$ is not already a field, then $D$ is always (identified with) a strict subset of $F$. For example, if $D = \mathbb{Z}$, then $F = \mathbb{Q}$ and $\eta : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is the [inclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_map).